# disable-gl-error-limit not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, google-chrome-devtools

Im using google chrome 57.
Under `chrome://gpu/` --> `Command Line Args` I have the following:

```
--use-spdy=off --disable-http2 --disable-gl-error-limit --flag-switches-begin --enable-es3-apis --enable-webgl-draft-extensions --flag-switches-end
```

but although I have this switch `disable-gl-error-limit`, Im still getting this msg:

```
WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.
```

and
 `Too many GL errors, not reporting any more for this context. use --disable-gl-error-limit to see all errors.`

Why its not working?
I want to see all warning and errors of Webgl.

Comment: while not a solution to your question, why not fix the errors happening until then first? If you're not completely abusing the API any errors logged after that message will be repeats of the already logged ones happening during your renderloop.

Comment: the error is 
`[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0000000015813810]RENDER WARNING: Render count or primcount is 0.` and it shows up about 230 times in t he same place and then I get the nsg about the limit. Nothing to do with this for now